How can I check whether two sets of integer vectors generate the same subgroup?
How can I check whether two finite sets of $n$ independent vectors in $\Bbb Z^n$ generate the same additive subgroup of $\Bbb Z^n$? For example, $\{(2,7),(5,3)\}$ and $\{(-3,4),(5,3)\}$ have the same span (I convinced myself by drawing a picture). I'm interested in the $n=2$ case as well as the general case.
A web search led me to the lattice, period lattice, and lattice problem articles. For $n=2$, after playing with some examples, I was thinking we could do something resembling the GCD algorithm to iteratively reduce the norms of the basis vectors (or maybe minimize their dot product, to make them "as orthogonal as possible"; or something similar to reach a basis corresponding to a point in the fundamental region). For arbitrary $n$, I wonder if this is essentially "shortest basis problem" or "shortest vector problem".
Motivation: I want visualize the "finite flatlands" that can be made out of squares (glued edge-to-edge with 4 squares meeting at each vertex). I convinced myself that these (at least the orientable ones) correspond to the quotients of $\Bbb Z^2$ by lattices, and figured out how to "reduce a point modulo the parallelogram corresponding to a given basis" in order to implement addition in $\Bbb Z^2/\Lambda$ ("moving around in the flatland"), and now I'm thinking about how to classify/parametrize these spaces (equivalently, the lattices) and higher-dimensional generalizations.

Write one set as a linear combination of the other set over rationals or reals. If the matrix of coefficients of those linear combinations has integer entries and determinant $\pm1$, then they generate the same additive subgroup.

For instance, in your example, $(-3,4) = 1\cdot (2,7) + (-1)\cdot (5,3)$ and $(5,3) = 0\cdot (2,7) + 1\cdot(5,3)$, so the matrix is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & -1 \0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, which is indeed an invertible integer matrix.

@Pranay thanks, I didn't think of that! (Because I guess what I really want to do is find a "canonical" basis for a given lattice, but this helps.)

@Pranay This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

@MartinBrandenburg. Sure. I’ll do that now.

for getting close to orthogonal, you want the LLL  lattice reduction algorithm. I suggest practicing with it in pari-gp  ... Next, in dimension 2, there is Gauss reduction; in dimension 3, people have worked out canonical forms based on work by Eisenstein.  https://math.mit.edu/~brubaker/PARI/PARIrefcard.pdf

Turning my comment into an answer:
Write every vector in the first set as a linear combination of second set of vectors over rationals (they must be rationals because all vectors have integer entries). Let $M$ be the matrix whose entries are the coefficients of these linear combinations. If $M \in \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$, i.e., if all entries of $M$ are integers and $\det M = \pm 1$, then the two sets generate the same additive subgroup of $\mathbb Z^n$.
In the given example, we have $(-3,4) = 1\cdot(2,7) +(-1)\cdot(5,3)$ and $(5,3)=0\cdot(2,7)+1\cdot(5,3)$, so the matrix is
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}
1&-1\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
whose entries are clearly integers and determinant is $1$. Therefore, both sets of vectors generate the same additive subgroup.
